# Bootstrap column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with a ul inside of it with 8 li's. I'm using bootstrap here, so in the end, they use up to 11 col's (col-md-1 etc...) The problem is their width. Most of them (Because of the length of the word inside of it) are with proper margins, but there are two which aren't.

Basicly I need to resize the column width to have more space within the li, but i'm not being able to...

Part of the code:

```
<li class="lastItem col-md-1"> <a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english..

This is one of the li's, i need to increase it's width so that it gets a proper spacing between the borders and the word

*I dont have enough rep to upload a image.. >.<

http://postimg.org/image/72ma5sh05/

Comment: Your English is fine ;) Could you upload a screenshot and maybe create a JSfiddle?

Comment: I would say don't use grid system for menu. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer to my own question is... to remove the bootstrap. Removed the bootstrap and gave exact padding values to all li's... and it worked.

Thanks for the effort :D

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more. I didn't really understand the issue. Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

`col-md-1` isn't a class that's usually assigned to a `<li>` structure. I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
// Using the Grid System
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <a href="#">Contacts</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <a href="#">Something</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <a href="#">Another Thing</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <a href="#">One More Thing</a>
  </div>
</div>

// Using the ul/li System (Exactly the same)
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
  <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Something</a></li>
  <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">Something Else</a></li>
  <li class="col-md-1"><a href="#">One More Thing</a></li>
</ul>
```

This way, the columns will align properly and resize responsively to the size of your browser window. `<ul><li>...` structure is fine, but it isn't responsive in the same way, so assigning the `col-md-*` class to it isn't the best idea.

Take a look at this Bootply to see an example of the code in action:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/BP1FXSlNbs)

Comment: That wouldn't help me since I need the items to be on a list. And why shouldn't I put col's in li's?

Comment: Do you want the list in-line? And generally you don't use that class on `<li>`. I mean nothing's stopping you, go for it, but I've never seen it used that way :P If you need more space, can you just use your code with `col-md-2`? I'm really confused what you want lol

Comment: Yes. For that i would just use a nav? The li itself would be too big. What i really want is just to have more space between the border and the word...

Comment: What's the word you're using? Made an edit, seems the `<ul><li>` structure works exactly the same when using the `col-md-*` class. Who knew!

Comment: Oh so there's some custom styling on there. Do you mind editing your question with the CSS? You probably just need more `padding` or a larger `margin` around the block element.

Comment: The css modifications are only "cosmetic" and to align the text to the center. None of it is touching width/padding/margin. However if I touch on that, it will overlay the other li's